# generic function to extract an array of a specific struct data member from an array of structs

Tags: c, function, macros, struct

If I have a struct, say

```
struct mystuff {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

and then I have an array of those structs,

```
struct mystuff array[] = {...};
```

now say I would like to extract the struct data member, a, into its own array,

```
int* get_mystuff_a(struct mystuff *array, int n)
{
    int i;
    int *a_array;

    a_array = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        a_array[i] = array[i].a;
    }
    return a;
}
```

now if i want to do the same for b, I have to write another function, but it will be almost identical apart from

```
b_array[i] = array[i].b;
```

is there a way i could write one generic function and specify the data member i want to extract as a parameter?

I think that a macro function may work, but I'm lost how you would actually write it

What would be even better is if you could also specify the data type, e.g. int, float, double etc. of the data member too - to make it even more generic

Comment: haha - i know that this is possible using the preprocessor - i just don't have the chops to actually write it, i haven't used the preprocessor that much and when I have I tend to get it wrong - need a push in the right direction

Comment: You could potentially use `offsetof`, as a parameter to a general function. But in my opinion a macro as suggested by Rodrigo would be safer.

Comment: its amazing what you can achieve with macros - i use uthash and utarray which is implemented completely inside its own header file using only macros - but for sure its difficult to understand/debug. I think there is a way of getting gcc to output the code after the preprocessor has run then you can step through that but I haven't tried it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing this as a macro is easy, not that it is always a good idea.

In this case, I think it is better to write a macro that builds a function, instead of trying to do the work directly inline:

1. Take your non-generic code.
2. Add `\` at the end of every line, because macros are one-line only.
3. Add `#define NAME(...) \` at the beginning.
4. Replace the macro arguments where needed.
5. Do not forget the extra parenthesis, if needed.

The result would be along the lines of:

```
#define GET_MYSTUFF(TYPE, FIELD) \
TYPE* get_mystuff_##FIELD(struct mystuff *array, int n) \
{ \
    int i; \
    TYPE *res_array; \
    res_array = malloc(n*sizeof(TYPE)); \
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) { \
        res_array[i] = array[i].FIELD; \
    } \
    return res_array; \
}
```

Now you create all your functions with:

```
GET_MYSTUFF(int, a)
GET_MYSTUFF(int, b)
GET_MYSTUFF(int, c)
```

You can even add the input array type as another parameter for the macro, but that is left as an exercise to the reader.

**UPDATE**: Note that this macro expand to a function definition, and you should not define your functions in the header file or else you will have duplicated definition errors. There are several solutions, pick your best:

1. Make your functions static (`static TYPE* get_mystuff_##FIELD(...`). This way every compilation unit that includes your function will get a copy of the function.
2. Move the definition of the functions to a `mystuff.c` file, and write only the function prototypes in `mystuff.h`. You can write these prototypes manually or create a macro for that:

   `#define GET_MYSTUFF_PROTO(TYPE, FIELD) TYPE* get_mystuff_##FIELD(struct mystuff *array, int n);`
3. With a bit of extra work, and if you want a bit of fun, you can use [X_Macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)!

#### mystuff.h

```
#ifndef GET_MYSTUFF
#define GET_MYSTUFF(TYPE, FIELD) \
    TYPE* get_mystuff_##FIELD(struct mystuff *array, int n);
#endif

GET_MYSTUFF(int, a)
GET_MYSTUFF(int, b)
GET_MYSTUFF(int, c)
```

#### mystuff.c

```
/* include for prototypes */
#include "mystuff.h"

#undef GET_MYSTUFF
#define GET_MYSTUFF(TYPE, FIELD) \
TYPE* get_mystuff_##FIELD(struct mystuff *array, int n) \
{ \
    int i; \
    TYPE *res_array; \
    res_array = malloc(n*sizeof(TYPE)); \
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) { \
        res_array[i] = array[i].FIELD; \
    } \
    return res_array; \
}

/* include for definitions */
#include "mystuff.h"
```

Comment: this will alleviate a lot of very similar code, which is good from a DRY perspective, but i acknowledge that functions like this are potentially poor practice in c. i will be scratching my head now figuring out how to make it agnostic to the input array of structs type

Comment: this approach is giving me lots of 'multiple definition' issues

Comment: how might one try and do the work 'inline' as it were

Comment: Well, are you defining your functions in a header file, aren't you? Please, see the updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the additional explanation - now got it working. i am still wondering whether it would be more elegant to actually write a macro that i call like a function wherever i need to in my code?

Comment: i.e. as opposed to writing a macro, then generating the appropriate functions, then calling those functions - would be nice to write GET_MYSTUFF(int, a) direct in my code rather than calling the 'intermediate' function, get_mystuff_a() that the macro has created

Comment: i think theres value in macros to reduce code duplication where the only thing changing is the type and the member variable name, but it does feel a bit painful - like C doesn't really want you to be doing it..

Comment: i really like the look of those xmacros - think they could definitely be incorporated to good effect..

Comment: @bph: About the macro doing the work directly, without a function, it can be done, but it is tricky because of the C syntax: you need a sentence block, but you also need to _return_ a value, somehow, and that is better done with a function. You can mark them as inline if your compiler supports it.

Comment: @bph: If you use the X-Macro header file to declare the structure in one go, declare the `get_*` functions in another, and define them in another... and you'll have the field declaration in only one place... and a lot of code no-one will want to look at!

Answer (score 1):

I came to a conclusion similar to rodrigo's one, the easiest thing to do would be to use a macro to declare your "getters" and then you could use them like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct mystuff {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

#define declare_getstuff_for(f) int* get_mystuff_##f(struct mystuff *array, int n) \
{ \
    int i; \
    int *a_array; \
\
    a_array = malloc(n*sizeof(int)); \
\
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) { \
        a_array[i] = array[i].f;  \
    }  \
    return a_array; \
}

declare_getstuff_for(a)
declare_getstuff_for(b)
declare_getstuff_for(c)


int main(void) {
    int *result1, *result2, *result3;
    struct mystuff array[3];
    struct mystuff el1, el2, el3;
    el1.a = el1.b = el1.c = 1;
    el2.a = el2.b = el2.c = 5;
    el3.a = el3.b = el3.c = 3;

    array[0] = el1;
    array[1] = el2;
    array[2] = el3;

    result1 = get_mystuff_a(array, 3);
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", result1[0], result1[1], result1[2]);

    result2 = get_mystuff_b(array, 3);
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", result2[0], result2[1], result2[2]);

    result3 = get_mystuff_c(array, 3);
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", result3[0], result3[1], result3[2]);

    // Now free your memory :)

    return 0;
}
```

Relevant pieces to keep in mind are the token-pasting operator `##` used to generate the function name, the usual macro substitution and the multi-line `\` marker.

Other than that: be aware that bugs in code like this are usually hard to debug. Always prefer a clean, maintainable code where possible and use macros where strictly necessary.

**Use with moderation :)**

Try it out: http://ideone.com/bbYsJK

Comment: i think i prefer having the required data member as an argument to the macro - seems cleaner that way

Comment: I'd agree with that if templates are out of the play.